# HTML5 and a Decibel meter

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, cordova

Is there anyway using HTML5 and Javascript to capture audio and get the live Decibel value of it? Can this be done on mobile devices using PhoneGap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't listen for audio through the browser itself unless you're using something like Flash. So PhoneGap COULD potentially work in devices other than the iPhone (no Flash support).

Eventhough PhoneGap **does** provide a [Media API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html) you cant just listen for the Mic input instead it will launch the audio capture device and give you a way to access the recorded Audio.

You could however write your own [PhoneGap Plugin](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins) that would give you this functionality.

**See**

- http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/ (XCode)
- [Android decibel meter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288813/android-decibel-meter) (Android)

And as I mentioned above you'd need to [write your own PhoneGap Plugin](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins) to use these.

Answer (score 1):

DecibelMeter: Monitor dB Levels Using HTML5 Audio API
https://github.com/jasonpecor/DecibelMeter